# Yodlee FastLink Integration url, secret and key

Tags: oauth, yodlee

I'm trying to setup oauth for fastlink on yodlee and your documentation says that I need to contact support for URL, consumer key, and secret. However, I'm using your free 30 day trial and don't have a "support person." On your website I couldn't find any contact information except for stackoverflow.

See bottom of:
https://developer.yodlee.com/Indy_FinApp/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Yodlee_FastLink_and_LAW_Guide/Yodlee_FastLink_Integration_Guide

Please advise,
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those lines were meant for client who are already with Yodlee.

Please go to below link to get the details
https://developer.yodlee.com/Indy_FinApp/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Yodlee_FastLink_and_LAW_Guide/Yodlee_FastLink_Integration_Guide/FastLink_Sandbox

https://developer.yodlee.com/Fastlink_2.0